# RecyclerView contents in NestedScrollView disappears after been scrolled out of view

Tags: android

I have a Recyclerview in a Nestedscrollview.It shows very well on loading showing all the contents of my customadapter but on scrolling some items away from sight and scrolling it back to them,the textviews will be gone.But imageviews doesnt behave like this.I have the Recyclerview in my Activity onCreate implemented this way

```
                styles=response.body();
                adapter=new DesignerStylesAdapter(styles);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DesignerActivity.this,RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false);
                mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and in activity layout file

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="52dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and in my custom adapter's onBindViewHolder,Im not calling setVisibility on any view

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,final int position){
        final Context context = holder.productPic.getContext();
        final CustomStyles style=styles.get(position);
        holder.productName.setText(style.getName());
        holder.productPrice.setText("₦"+ NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(style.getCustomPrice()));
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(style.getPhoto1())
                .into(holder.productPic);

    }
```

Someone kindly help out,Ive been stuck on this issue for the whole day.

Comment: why `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`?

Comment: I added it, while trying to make it work.adding and removing it doesnt change anything...For the one in nestedscrollview, I have a collapsible toolbar on it that's why

Comment: two years have passed and nobody has answered. Have you solved it?